# Trouble with second monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors

I rencently have a second monitor and I can't get it to work the way I wanted. When I click on Opera brower it's show up on my laptop screen but when I open Firefox it open in my second monitor, how can i fix that ? I want my laptop screen for music and other stuff while working the main jobs in my second monitor

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ubuntu, I think you can just change the primary display to MONITOR 2. Although I found some other bugs about this, you can still try it and see what will happen to your monitor.